# Can I find the circle radius from the set of points that fill it in?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a set of 2D points (say P, many points in the form [x,y]) that mostly make a filled in circle (they are all mostly less than some R distance from the mass center of all points in the set but there are outliers all around). This is the measurement data so the set is somewhat noisy, and I cannot use the trivial *max(P)-min(P)* to find the diameter. Any single outlier breaks such a naive approach and some points are "flying" very far away.

So far, I computed the histogram of the distance between all points in the set P, and pick the diameter from the distribution, as the value two standard deviations (sigmas) away from the mean towards the larger side. This improved the results but the estimated diameter now depends on the picking place in the histogram.

Is there any other noise-aware way to estimate the likely diameter of the circle, assuming that the majority of the points do make into that circle? If found the formula that can tell the diameter from the points lying on the circle boundary, but in my case this boundary is not known (the points are filling in the circle in entirety). Finding it may add more noise to the data.

Ideally I would like to have the estimation of the ellipse (major and minor diameters), but it is not stretched too much so also circle would be good enough.

All parts of the circle are equally represented in the set and have some minimal distance between them as all values are integers. There are enough points in the for the circle to be easily visible by human sight. There are no duplicates.

Comment: Could you exclude the external points based on the distances to say three closest neighboring points?  You can use the pairwise distance histogram to find the limit, the same way you are doing now.  If a point does not have say at least three neighbors within twice the smallest histogram peak distance, it is "alone", and should be discarded from the circle consideration.  (But do not discard the point from the neighbor check, or you'll fiddle the point set down to a single point!)